# Beanstalk private keys

Tags: ssh, private-key, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have managed to lock myself out of ssh access to one of our boxes. I do know that one of our Beanstalk deployment public keys is in the authorised_keys file, so if I could just get the matching private key from Beanstalk I could get back on and avoid the long winded alternative.
Is there a way? There is nothing obvious in the admin login.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

> Note Amazon EC2 doesn't keep a copy of your private key; therefore, if
>   you lose a private key, there is no way to recover it. If you lose the
>   private key for an instance store-backed instance, you can't access
>   the instance; you should terminate the instance and launch another
>   instance using a new key pair. If you lose the private key for an
>   EBS-backed Linux instance, you can regain access to your instance. For
>   more information, see Connecting to Your Linux Instance if You Lose
>   Your Private Key.